# problem with an automation code for downloading videos from a YouTube channel

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, pytube

Good afternoon everyone, I have a problem with some code in Python. When running the code, the videos are not saved in the folder I want them to be saved, it only opens the channel page and nothing else. Could someone help me with this problem please?

This is the code: (in channel link the channel link will go)

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from time import sleep
import time
from random import randint
import requests
from pytube import YouTube
# Open browser
driver = webdriver.Firefox()

url = "https://channel_link"

#Get youtube video
def get_video_youtube(driver,url):
    driver.get(url)
    time.sleep(randint(5, 9))
    driver.get(url+"/videos")

    ht = driver.execute_script("return document.documentElement.scrollHeight;")

    while True:
        prev_ht = driver.execute_script("return document.documentElement.scrollHeight;")
        driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.documentElement.scrollHeight);")
        time.sleep(3)
        ht = driver.execute_script("return document.documentElement.scrollHeight;")

      #  element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@name='q']")

        if (prev_ht == ht):
            break
        links = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//input[@id='video-title']")

        with open('d:\\somefile.txt', 'w') as the_file:
            for link in links:
                print(link.get_attribute("title"))
                print(link.get_attribute("href"))
                yt = YouTube(link.get_attribute("href"))
                hd = yt.streams.get_highest_resolution()
                hd.download("D:\\youtube1\\")

                the_file.writelines(link.get_attribute("href")+'\n')
                sleep(3)

get_video_youtube(driver, url)
```

Then, pycharm does not generate any errors, it just runs and finishes but does not save anything

Comment: [When should code formatting be used for non-code text?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254990/when-should-code-formatting-be-used-for-non-code-text) -- backticks should **only** surround source code and nothing else.

Comment: does this directory `D:\youtube1\` exist? If yes, do you have the write permision there?

Comment: Yes it exists, I am saving it in a folder on my USB, and in the directory it appears with the name USB (D:). I guess since it's my USB, I do have permission